# Web page works ok on all browsers except ps3. On Ps3 browser, page won't scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, actionscript-3, playstation3

I'm not sure why the ps3 browser won't scroll down the rest of the web page; it works on all pc browsers ok.  The site contains a flash swf file (as3), some small pictures and a little text. Other than that its just html, css, and js(for swf file embedding).

[Website Link](http://terrydennissoper.com/wisdomwheel/)

Comment: Doesn’t scroll down in Opera on Desktop either, no scrollbar visible … so I guess you must have actively done something to suppress it.

Comment: thanks I'll take a look at the js embedding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't scroll because you have this:

`body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}`

Which hides the scrollbars, to fix this remove `overflow:hidden`